# Text box next to image and another image

Tags: html, css

i'm having trouble with some css/html again, i want text, then two images next to it, the first (most outside) div is the width of the page as it just works as a 'background color strip' and then within this div i want another div 950px X 250px and within that div 480px x 250px for the images on the right (which i have managed kind of) but when i add text it pushes them down.

i need the text to be on the left, the images to be on the right (just two seperate divs) containted within the content div, which is centered in the background div.

all divs need to be the same height.

the code is below

CSS

```
.greybackground {
background-color: #eee;
height: 230px;
width: 1920px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 10px;


}

.greybackgroundcontent {
height: 250px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  


}

.greybackgroundimage {
height: 250px;
width: 480px;
margin-left: 490px;
display:inline-block;

vertical-align:middle;



}
```

HTML

```
<div class="greybackground">

<div class="greybackgroundcontent">

<div class="greybackgroundtext">

<P>KLEENZONE KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE</P>





 <div class="greybackgroundimage"><img src="images/officezoom.jpg" />

 <img src="images/polozoom.jpg"/>


</div>

</div>

</div>

</div>





 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<style type="text/css">
    .greybackground {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 230px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;


    }

    .greybackgroundcontent {
    height: 250px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  


    }

    .greybackgroundimage {
    height: 250px;
    width: 480px;
    /*margin-left: 490px;*/
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: inline;


    }

    #txt{float:left;}

    </style>

    <div class="greybackground">

    <div class="greybackgroundcontent">

    <div id='txt'>Kleenzone can cater to cleaning of all applications and sizes.</div>

    <div class="greybackgroundimage">

        <img src="images/officezoom.jpg" />

        <img src="images/polozoom.jpg"/>

    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: the images are pushed down as above but they're also not on the left either

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FASZ7/1/)

**CSS**

```
.greybackground {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 230px;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;


    }

    .greybackgroundcontent {
    height: 250px;
    width: 950px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;  


    }

    .greybackgroundimage {
    height: 250px;
    width: 480px;
    /*margin-left: 490px;*/
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display: inline;


    }
```

**UPDATED QUERY:**

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FASZ7/2/)

Css issue,Now solved working fine in IE7 onwards.. Check this updated code,if you have any doubt let me know.

**CSS**

```
.greybackgroundimage {
    width: 480px;
    /*margin-left: 490px;*/
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline;


    }
```

[**LAST UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/FASZ7/4/)

Now div is seperated with 2 sides horizontally with same height which you asked.

Just put this code in your browser then check it...

**HTML**

```
<div class="greybackground">
<div class="greybackgroundcontent">
<div id="greybackgroundtext">
<P>KLEENZONE KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE
KLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONEKLEENZONE</P>
</div>
<div id="greybackgroundimage"><img src="images/officezoom.jpg" />
<img src="images/polozoom.jpg"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.greybackground {
background-color: #eee;
width: 100%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.greybackgroundcontent {
background-color: #eee;
height: 250px;
width: 950px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;  
}
#greybackgroundtext,#greybackgroundimage {
height: 250px;
 width:50%;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: sorry but still not working, the images are now on the left and text above this pushing it below the grey background, give me 5 mins ill rephrase and retype my question which may make it easier!

Comment: all done now, you got anything figured out for that?

Comment: much better! however the background is too big and goes past the images, adding a height to the background css doesnt change it either.

Comment: ok,i didnt consider about the height & width of the images,if you have any more doubt let me know

Answer (score -1):

You can use table format to display the text and images side by side.
Apply the css to `tr` elements instead of `div` elements.